# How to add custom operator in Tensorflow Lite with attributes

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I added custom operator in Tensorflow by following this instructions:
https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op

Now I want to add same operator to Tensorflow Lite.
I followed [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/g3doc/custom_operators.md) instructions to add custom operator in TF Lite, but it does not say anything about how to add custom operator with attributes.
Like this:

```
REGISTER_OP("CustomOpName")
.Attr("T: {float}")
.Attr("scale_factor: int")
.Input("x: T")
.Output("out: T")
```

I tried to do that like builtin operators to cast TfLiteNode* node to a custom parameter struct like TfLiteLocalResponseNormParams, but the problem is that TfLiteNode* node is equal to NULL.

Comment: have you found a solution to this yet?

Comment: The instruction link you provided has been updated recently. I have successfully added new ops without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it similarly to the [mfcc kernel](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/mfcc.cc#L52). The attributes you define in your custom tensorflow op will appear as a [flexbuffer](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flexbuffers.html) and can be easily queried.